# EXCEL SUMPRODUCT FORMULA

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I have an Excel workbook that has sheets that include columns where it is required to average the lowest 7 from 25 values excluding any with a 0, e.g any cells with a value greater than 1.  In the example below column Z is used and the values are contained in rows 13 to 38.  In a number of rows the sum of the value in column Z is 0.

The formula I have is =SUMPRODUCT(SMALL(Z$13:Z$38,{1,2,3,4,5,6,7}))/7

This works but only if, for example, the rows that return a 0 are either blank or contains a "-".

This creates a problem as the rows have formula that are the sum of other cells in that row. For example Z20 has a formula that is the sum of M20 plus W20 which are the sum of D20:L20 & N20:V20 respectively.  Although D20:L20 and N20:V20 are unpopulated the sum in M20 & W20 both return a 0.  The cells D20:L20 & N20:V20 will only be populated at a later date.

By entering a "-" or pressing delete to remove the 0 I also remove the formula. It then becomes necessary to re-enter the formula when populating the cells which is possible but not ideal due to the number of sheets involved and potential for error.

Is there a solution to this problem?

Thanks,

F

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One work-around is to change the other formulae instead, e.g. for Z20, instead of using

> =M20+W20

use

> =IF((M20+W20)=0,"-",(M20+W20))

which will set the cell equal to "-" whenever the formula returns a zero.

Comment: Gwyn, your suggestion solved my issue with the column.  I have one remaining issue, another column is referenced to Col Z with for example =Z20-AA20 & the resulting sum is inserted into BB20.  The issue is again the 0 for the same reasons.  I have tried to manipulate your formula to insert a "-" when Z20 has a "-" etc and cannot get it to work.  Do you have an idea?

Comment: For your new column BB, if you always want it to be "-" when Z or AA is "-", use (in BB20): 
                                                  
=IF(Z20="-","-",(IF(AA20="-","-",(Z20-AA20)))) 

if, instead, you wish to interpret those "-" as zero for the calculation, use:
                                                                   
=(IF(Z20="-",0,Z20))-(IF(AA20="-",0,AA20))

Comment: If you don't get a better option in the next 48hours, consider accepting my answer by clicking the check mark next to it.

Comment: If I'm adding the same comment twice then it's because I'm new to the forum.  The solution worked for Col Z.  In part it created another issue.  Col Z is linked to Col AB by a simple formula, Z20-AA20.  Col AB has the same issue that Col Z had in that it cannot have a 0 in the rows that are not populated by data.  I've tried to manipulate the solution provided for Col Z but I've not been able to get it to work.  If Z20 is populated by a "-" I need to find a solution that allows AB to have a "-" if AA is a number.

Comment: Check my first comment, Replace the BB with AB and that should solve your problem